# 2-D Elastic Collision

Tags: homework-and-exercises, collision

> A bocce ball moving at 3.60 m/s strikes a second identical ball initially at rest in a perfectly elastic collision.
>
> The first ball moves off at a 36 degree  angle from its original path and is moving at 2.91 m/s.
>
> Find the velocity of the second ball (magnitude and direction).

Let's define variables:

The moving bocce ball will be considered to be $m_1$ with a velocity $v_1$ of 3.6 m/s.

The bocce ball at rest will be considered to be $m_2$ with a velocity of $v_2$ of 0 m/s.

I used the following equation:

$m_1v_1 + m_2v_2 = m_1v'_1\cos \theta_1 + m_1v'_2 \cos \theta_2$

Mass cancels out, they're 2 identical balls.

$3.6 = 3.6 \cos 36^o + v'_2 \cos \theta_2$  for the x component.
$0 = 2.91 \sin 36^o + v'_2 \sin \theta_2$ for the y component.

I am attempting to create systems of equations to solve this problem.

However, this equation seems to be missing too much information, therefore I believe I have set the problem up wrongly. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Comment: @Kyle in what way can I improve this post? I have shown my attempt at solving the problem and what equations I believe are relevant.

Comment: That's great for you, but we don't solve homework for you here, we answer questions about specific physics concepts.

Comment: If you want to improve the post, you need to edit out the homework aspect and ask the specific concept that's giving you trouble.

Comment: @Kyle That's fine. I don't need you to give me the answer. I need guidance about a problem that I am stuck on. I want to know how to do it, not know what the answer is.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much how we define homework questions here.

Comment: @Kyle yeah but I don't need something like `ok here the answer is *` I need something like `Ok you screwed up here so go back and reuse this equation but this time make sure you *` or like `nah you don't need systems of equations here so instead, use the * formula and plug in numbers using that`.

Comment: Yeah, that's not saying anything different than what you said in the previous statement, to which my above comment still stands. I'm not sure what the confusion about this is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35697/discussion-between-registered-user-and-kyle-kanos).

Comment: Go review the conditions and concepts which define what an elastic collision actually is. You're missing something crucial from that definition.

Comment: @BillN Total kinetic energy is conserved and is the same before/after the collision?

Comment: Try it and see what happens...the algebra gets messy, so be meticulous!

Comment: @BillN labeling all the stuff does get tedious. thanks for your help!

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 1):

The collision is perfectly elastic, meaning total kinetic energy, in addition to momentum, is conserved. If you set up the correct equation, you will have enough information to solve the problem.

Comment: I think this is what I was missing in the equations. thank you